# How to generate a 13 digit number from a string in python

Tags: python

I want to create barcodes reports in python and i am using reportlab for it. I can generate a EAN13 barcode from a 13 digit number.

How to generate a 13 digit number from any string such that same number is generated each time when same string is used.

e.g.

```
str1 = 'abcxyz123'
## do something on str1
## a 13 digit number is generated e.g. 2134332512345 is generated everytime when string is 'abcxyz123'
```

Comment: Hmm...like **Hash**, but 13 digit numbers?

Comment: This seems a bit underspecified to me ... for example `lambda s: '1' * 13` is a function which would meet the criterion you specified.  What is the range of possible values for the inputs?  How well randomized does the output have to be?

Comment: You need to read about hashing algorithms. As stated currently, question is too broad. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I have a no. of products with each having different name. I just want to assign a 13 digit number to each based on their names.

Comment: @ManishGupta -- How many products is this?  Could you start with `0000000000001` and just keep incrementing for each new product?  You could store the product-name -> EAN13 barcode in some sort of database.

Comment: I have like more than 5000 products. with names with string length 7 to 25 approx. i want to be sure that the 13 digit number i am using for barcoding  must relate to that particular product name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply use [hashLib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) as:

```
import hashlib

str1 = 'abcxyz123'
str2 = 'abcxyzhjk'
str3 = 'abcxyz123'

hash1 = hashlib.sha1()
hash1.update(str1)
print str(int(hash1.hexdigest(), 16))[:13]
>>> 2655706373072

hash2 = hashlib.sha1()
hash2.update(str2)
print str(int(hash2.hexdigest(), 16))[:13]
>>> 1219934364452

hash3 = hashlib.sha1()
hash3.update(str3)
print str(int(hash3.hexdigest(), 16))[:13]
>>> 2655706373072
```

The `hash.hexdigest()` returns hex value which could be easily converted to integer using `int(hex, 16)`, and then limiting the integer to 13 digits only by converting it to `str()` and then slicing the string.